# Difference Between FileMapping and Istream Binary

Tags: c++, istream

I have two code samples, the first is the following:

```
//THIS CODE READS IN THE CALC.EXE BINARY INTO MEMORY BUFFER USING ISTREAM
ifstream in("notepad.exe", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

int size = in.tellg();

char* buffer = new char[size];

ifstream input("calc.exe", std::ios::binary);

input.read(buffer, size);
```

This is the second:

```
//THIS CODE GETS FILE MAPPING IMAGE OF SAME BINARY
handle = CreateFile("notepad.exe", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

mappinghandle = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);

image = (DWORD) MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
```

My question is, what exactly is the difference between these two methods?  If we are ignoring the sizing issue that is better handled by file mapping, are these two objects returned essentially the same?  Will not the `image` variable point to essentially the same thing as the `buffer` variable - this being an image of the binary executable in memory?  What are all the differences between the two?

Comment: Well, you'd have a devil of a time getting the second compiling on Linux...

Comment: You should add the proper variable declarations to your second example. E. g. MapViewOfFile returns a pointer, casting it to a DWORD makes no sense when you want to access the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method using std::ifstream actually copies the data of the file into RAM, when input.read() is called whereas MapViewOfFile doesn't access the file data.

MapViewOfFile() returns a pointer, but the data will only actually be read from disk when you access the virtual memory that the pointer points to.

```
// This creates just a "view" of the file but doesn't read data from the file.
const char *buffer = reinterpret_cast<const char*>( MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0) );

// Only at this point the file actually gets read. The virtual memory manager now 
// reads a page of 4KiB into memory.
char value = buffer[ 10 ];
```

To further illustrate the difference, say we read a byte at offset 12345 from the memory-mapped file:

```
char value = buffer[ 12345 ];
```

Now the virtual memory manager won't read all the data up to this offset, but instead only map the page that is closest to that offset into memory. That would be the page located between offset 12288 (=4096*3) and 16384 (=4096*4).

Answer (score 0):

The first one reads from the file into a buffer, the buffer is independent of the original file.

The second one is accessing the file itself, you won't be able to delete the file while a mapping exists, and although you can't make changes because you have a read-only mapping, changes made to that file outside your program can be visible in your mapping.